# Using HAML for static pages in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I want to create a static page, one that will be served by Nginx instead of rails. I want to write it in HAML. Is there a way to use the assets pipeline for this, instead of adding a line to my build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that *something* needs to kick off your conversion. Whether you're using HAML, sprockets, jekyll, or something else isn't the point; a monitoring or periodic process of some kind is still required to start the conversion process.

You may want to use guard, autotest, cron, inotify, or any of a host of other tools to kick off your conversion script whenever the contents of your HAML file change. Personally, I think cron is the simplest option, but an inotify callback may be the most resource-efficient choice. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Settled on a HAML compilation in my build script. this sucks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just compile your Haml file to HTML file using `haml` command:

```
haml -qf html5 [infile] [outfile]
```

And then you can serve it without Rails.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a way not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a static page, then make sure your page can be cached by the browser or the server. That does not exactly answer your question, but serves the same goal I guess.